# How add "or" in switch statements?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

This is what I want to do:

```
switch(myvar)
{
    case: 2 or 5:
    ...
    break;

    case: 7 or 12:
    ...
    break;
    ...
}
```

I tried with "case: 2 || 5" ,but it didn't work.

The purpose is to not write same code for different values.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? Does it give you syntax errors, or logical errors?

Comment: Starting with C# 9, this exact syntax is allowed.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

By stacking each switch case, you achieve the OR condition.

```
switch(myvar)
{
    case 2:
    case 5:
    ...
    break;

    case 7:
    case 12:
    ...
    break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Joel, it doesn't support fall through but it DOES support stacking (e.g., an empty case 2 in this answer executes the case 5 section).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Good job, your work is appreciated.

Answer (score 44):

You do it by [stacking case labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement):

```
switch(myvar)
{
    case 2:
    case 5:
    ...
    break;

    case 7: 
    case 12:
    ...
    break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 27):

[You may do this as of C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements):

```
switch(myvar)
{
    case 2 or 5:
        // ...
        break;

    case 7 or 12:
        // ...
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is more readable then allowing it fall through, downside it's C# 9.0 up only as you pointed out.

Answer (score 22):

```
case 2:
case 5:
do something
break;
```

Answer (score 18):

Case-statements automatically fall through if you don't specify otherwise (by writing break). Therefor you can write

```
switch(myvar)
{
   case 2:
   case 5:
   {
      //your code
   break;
   }
```

// etc...
    }

Comment: Note that this is only true for empty cases. Cases with actual body do not automatically fall through.

Answer (score 7):

Since C# 8 there are [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) that are better readable: no `case`, `:` and `break;`/`return` needed anymore. Combined with C# 9's [logical patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns):

```
static string GetCalendarSeason(DateTime date) => date.Month switch
{
    3 or 4 or 5 => "spring",
    6 or 7 or 8 => "summer",
    9 or 10 or 11 => "autumn",
    12 or 1 or 2 => "winter",
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(date), $"Date with unexpected month: {date.Month}."),
};
```

Limitation: with this syntax, at the right of the `=>` you cannot use curly braces (`{` and `}`) for statements.

Answer (score 6):

The example for [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) shows that you can't stack non-empty `case`s, but should use `goto`s:

```
// statements_switch.cs
using System;
class SwitchTest 
{
   public static void Main()  
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Coffee sizes: 1=Small 2=Medium 3=Large"); 
      Console.Write("Please enter your selection: "); 
      string s = Console.ReadLine(); 
      int n = int.Parse(s);
      int cost = 0;
      switch(n)       
      {         
         case 1:   
            cost += 25;
            break;                  
         case 2:            
            cost += 25;
            goto case 1;           
         case 3:            
            cost += 50;
            goto case 1;             
         default:            
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please select 1, 2, or3.");            
            break;      
       }
       if (cost != 0)
          Console.WriteLine("Please insert {0} cents.", cost);
       Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your business.");
   }
}
```

Comment: -1 The msdn link has a stacked example further down the page.  At any rate, stacked cases work, especially in this question where the stated purpose is to not write duplicate code as done in your case 1 and 2.

Comment: Usefull answer as example of "goto case".

Comment: I hate goto statements what is this 1992?