# Can I have a Switch Statement with more than one Case Criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Can I have a switch statement like this:

...

```
switch (temp)
{
case "NW" or "New":
temp = "new stuff"
break;
}
```

...

Comment: how can the string temp be both "NW" AND "New"? do you mean OR?

Comment: You don't really mean AND do you, you mean OR - how would it be possible for temp to = "NW" and "New"? Anyway, see all the fallthrough answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, but you can use (at least in Java)

```
switch (temp) {
    case "NW":
    case "New":
       temp="new stuff";
       break;
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't allow fall-through case statements. Might be worth adding it. Your answer IS perfect for Java though :D (+1)

Comment: @devinb - sorry, I don't get what that means. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: C# does allow fall through in this one special case were there is nothing in a particular case. So the above is valid C#

Comment: @Martin, you are correct. I'd edit my comment but I can't. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes. This is how it is done.

```
switch (temp)
{
   case "NW":
   case "New":
     temp = "new stuff"
     break;
}
```

Actually, I answered this very [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848472/how-add-or-in-case-statements/848475#848475) before.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
switch (temp)
{
case "NW":
case "New":
temp = "new stuff"
break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming C#, you want:

```
switch(temp)
{
    case "NW":
    case "New":
        temp = "new stuff";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (temp) {
    case "NW":
    case "New":
        temp = "new stuff"
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about C#, and have good answers there, but just for perspective (and for anyone else reading that might find it useful), here's the VB answer:

```
Select Case temp
  Case "NW", "New"
    temp = "new stuff"
  Case Else
    'something else...
End Select
```

Notice that there's no "break"--VB does not drop through cases. On the other hand, you *can* have multiple match conditions on a single case.

Be care you **DON'T** do this

```
...
  Case "NW" Or "New"
...
```

What you have there is a single condition with a bitwise Or between the two terms....