# Error 2 Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, console

Visual Studio is telling me that I can't apply an or statement in my switch.

Can I even apply that to my switch at all?

```
         Second_Chance_2 = System.Console.ReadLine();

            switch (Second_Chance_2)
            {
                case "":                             
                        Console.WriteLine("Error");
                        break;

                case "Alpha Area" || "alpha area": 
                       System.Console.WriteLine("Now The Real Game Begins");
                        break;

                default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Error");
                        break;
            }
```

Comment: In future, please try to post a *short* but complete program demonstrating your problem. You've posted over 150 lines of badly-indented code, *very* little of which is relevant to the problem at hand. If you find you need to add extra words to your post, that's a good indication that you haven't given enough information about what you're trying to achieved - *don't* just type rubbish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How add "or" in switch statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848472/how-add-or-in-switch-statements)

Answer (score 1):

This `||` is the logical or operator and can be applied only to boolean values or expression that can be evaluated to a boolean.

That being said, you can only write

```
a || b
```

when both `a` and `b` are of type `bool` or expression that are evaluated to a `bool`.

That being said, this

```
 case "Alpha Area" || "alpha area":
```

is not valid

You could achieve that you want like below:

```
case "Alpha Area":
case "alpha area":
```

We do this when we want to a `switch` to go the same branch for two or more different cases.

Answer (score 1):

You got the wrong syntax, this:

```
 case "Alpha Area" || "alpha area":
```

should be:

```
 case "Alpha Area":
 case "alpha area":
```

Alternatively you could also convert the switch string to lower case to have only 1 case statement:

```
 switch (Second_Chance_2.ToLowerInvariant())
 {
      ...
      case "alpha area":
```